# Regex not matching in java

Tags: java, regex

I've created a regex to identify decimal numbers within a string in java:

```
"(?<before>\\D|^)(?<group>-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?)(?<after>\\D|$)"
```

When testing it against "4-3", I get no result. What's strange is that on regex101.com I copy-pasted the same regex (it automatically removed the double backslash since it's not within quotes):

```
(?<before>\D|^)(?<group>-?\d+(\.\d+)?)(?<after>\D|$)
```

I retested it on "4-3" and got 1 match on "4-", which is what I'd expect java to find.

Did I do something wrong with my regex or the backslashes which explains the problem? If not, does this mean java has a bug/ interprets regex differently?

I'm using jdk.1.8.0_05

Comment: what is the issue making it simple `\d+-\d+`

Comment: if you want to find only the decimal numbers then why you make this `(\.\d+)?` part as optional?

Comment: Integers are also decimal numbers. My question is not about the correctness of my regex but rather why it works on the regex101 site and not in java.

Comment: Can you put sample data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I retested it on `4-3` and got 1 match on **`4-`**, which is what I'd expect Java to find. **My question is not about the correctness of my regex but rather why it works on the regex101 site and not in Java**.

You need to define the named group to return the captured input subsequence by the given named group.

```
String s  = "4-3";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<before>\\D|^)(?<group>-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?)(?<after>\\D|$)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
  System.out.println(m.group("before"));  //=> ""
  System.out.println(m.group("group"));   //=> "4"
  System.out.println(m.group("after"));   //=> "-"
}
```

Comment: You're absolutely right. It does work in java. The problem was coming from the way I ingest and exploit those regex, which seems to have a bug. Thanks